# How do I add OpenCV to LD_LIBRARY path in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, pkg-config

I used [this](http://learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/) link to install OpenCV.

**What works**:

1.OpenCV works fine with python (running from terminal).

2.I can import opencv libraries in a single C++ program.

**What does not work** :

When the code is spread across multiple and you need to build it using CMake.

Here's my CmakeLists.txt :

1.`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)`

2.`project(Image_processing)`

3.`set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)`

4.`find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)`

5.`include_directories(/home/user/opencv/build)`

6.`add_executable(main main.cpp)`

7.`target_link_libraries(project_name ${OpenCV_LIBS})`

Errors (can regenerate them by commenting lines 4,5 and 7 in above CMake file):

`undefined reference` to OpenCV functions.

`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "Image_processing" which is not
  built by this project.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct it with:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(Image_processing)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `CMakeLists.txt`, the exe-name is not matching with the target-link-name. I modify the line, then it works on my PC.

---

The `CMakeLists.txt` of an `OpenCV Project`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(Image_processing)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

#include_directories(/home/user/opencv/build)

add_executable(Image_processing main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Image_processing ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```